# Weird white space when body font size set to vw and all sizes to em

Tags: html, css, whitespace

To have a fully responsive website, I used the wizardry technique. There you set the body font size to 1vh and based on that you set everything else in em: the padding, width, font-sizes etc. Here is the link to the technique: https://wizardry-technique.webflow.io

Now in Chrome, I am experiencing a weird white space as shown on the screenshot beneath.

In the Chrome inspector, I tried to check off everything and came to the conclusion it is the font size that makes the white space appear.

Link to the page: https://www.designdan.london/vcard

Any ideas about what I am doing wrong, or how to solve it?

[image: Weird white space]

Comment: Please add a [mcve] of the code itself to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not about the `font-size`, but the border with `em` units. The result is a size in fractions of pixels that is not correctly rendered (a sub-pixel problem). I have tried many solutions with no results. My advice is to change the border to px.

Below I managed to replicate the problem (at least on my browser I have the same visual problem as you) in the right and bottom sides of the first square.

```css
.businesscard {
  float:left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 0.33333em #000000;  
}


.content {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  background-color: #333333;
}

.px-border {
  margin-left: 25px;
  border: solid 5px #000000;  
}
```

```html
<div class="businesscard">
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="businesscard px-border">
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>
```